# Can WCF Data Services or RIA Services be implemented with NHibernate?

Tags: wcf, silverlight, nhibernate, wcf-ria-services

From what [I read on the internets](http://wildermuth.com/2009/09/29/Choosing_a_Data_Access_Layer_for_Silverlight_3), WCF Data Services seem to be bound to data access via Entity Framework on the server.

Is there a way to have NHibernate access mapped in the same way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WCF RIA Services can certainly be used with NHibernate, and I believe WCF Data Services can too. Both frameworks build on top of [`IQueryable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562.aspx) which can be provided by [LINQ to NHibernate](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/07/26/nhibernate-linq-1.0-released.aspx)

See this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2009/08/06/business-apps-example-for-silverlight-3-rtm-and-net-ria-services-july-update-part-nhibernate.aspx) from Brad Abrams, where he uses RIA Services with NHibernate.

Comment: Also, check out this sample http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/RiaServices/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4316

Answer (score 2):

WCF Data Services and NHibernate have limitations you should be aware of.  There is a bit more to the picture besides just IQueryable, have a look for your self:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataservices/thread/fcdaca20-73ea-4abb-b70b-981fe2728351