# RIA Services Library not creating expected folder

Tags: .net, visual-studio, wcf, wcf-ria-services

When adding a new project and choosing WCF RIA Services Class Library, my solution shows one additional project, say, RIAServicesLibary1. However, there is no RIAServicesLibrary1.Web project shown.

However, if I browse to the solution in windows explorer, I see both RIAServicesLibrary1 and RIAServicesLibrary1.Web folders. The RIAServicesLibrary1 folder is populated with files, but the .Web folder is completely empty. I have been trying to figure out why this is happening to no avail.

I have installed both the RiaServices and toolkit from the microsoft site. I am running VS2010 on .NET framework 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns the out project was failing to create properly due to some conflict in national instruments measurement studio (VS plugin). After uninstalling that, the project created successfully.